# Why is React significantly slower with many items?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

**Why is React so slow when dealing with a large list (say 100,000) of virtual-only nodes (e.g. components that render null), and no DOM updates? Are there any tricks to shortcut those bottlenecks?**

Here are two different demos that allow adding many items to the screen and doing very simple updates on each tick (based on the PIXI bunnymark). To be clear, although tips are appreciated, this is not a question about React usage (which would make deciphering my code important), it's a question about React's ability to reconcile 100,000 virtual nodes:

**Plain**

[demo](https://dakom.github.io/baseline-pixi-bunnymark) - [source](https://github.com/dakom/baseline-pixi-bunnymark)

**React**

[demo](https://dakom.github.io/react-pixi-bunnymark) -  [source](https://github.com/dakom/react-pixi-bunnymark)

Now - I understand that the React version is going to be slower. But **what causes the difference to be so drastic? In other words - why is React so slow when there are no DOM updates?** (it takes me about 100,000 bunnies in Plain to get to what feels like 8,000 on the React version, and the Plain version is still more responsive).

Here's a few relevant points about the react implementation:

1. The fact that it uses PIXI is *probably* irrelevant, I'm guessing- since among other reasons it's used in both demos. Direct WebGL or Canvas updates would probably also have the same issues even if the net result is a bit faster (on both sides).
2. The architecture for this version might be a little tough to read - so it may help to say it in English. Fundamentally, all paths render `null` and updates are simply passed to PIXI in `componentWillReceiveProps()`. Of course nodes who have children render() the children but this does not add anything to the DOM.
3. It has been suggested to use a custom renderer altogether - but I'm not sure why that would make a difference considering the above. In other words- if the elements are all virtual, does the renderer really make a difference? More to the point - **is there hard data somewhere to back up this claim that the bottleneck is the swappable renderer?**
4. One might wonder why in the world adding React to the mix here is even worthwhile, considering PIXI has its own scene graph and diffing algorithms. That's a valid question but outside the scope here.
5. On the other hand, one might wonder why PIXI and not WebGL/Canvas directly. The short answer is that PIXI makes lots of things simple like nested hierarchies that propagate transforms.

Overall - my goal is to have a tree of React (or some other declarative framework) that allows writing  something like:

```
<Container position={pos}>
  <Container rotation={rot}>
    <Sprite texture={tex}/>
  </Container>
</Container>
```

and having that map directly to PIXI.

That would be awesome if it were performant.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but I personally think that your question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. One would need to go through both of your repositories and read what's probably hundreds of lines of code to understand your implementation. In addition, you are bringing up as many as 5 points for discussion. I suggest you revisit your question and format it to be smaller; include some code from your app, but only the relative bits; explain your implementation. Start with a smaller (sub-)problem, and then open a new question once the first one is answered.

Comment: Thanks. I hesitated before posting this here precisely for the reasons you raise. However, I've bolded the actual questions - everything else (including the demo and source code) are only to demonstrate the issue. I am not asking questions about the code, I'm asking why React is slow when there's no DOM updates

Comment: It is, at least for me, impossible to answer without understanding how this works and how it is implemented. The answer might be very straightforward, or it might not be. One would have to dig into your project a bit before saying for sure.

Comment: I believe it should be a fairly straightforward answer from the perspective of the _internals_ of React. This is not a question about React usage (which would make deciphering my code important), it's a question about React's ability to reconcile 100,000 virtual nodes.

Comment: I've clarified the question up top, thank you for your comments